# What is the most efficient way to copy results of a JSON array of objects to another array based on a property

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js

Say I have an array

```
var myArray = [{id:10, country:"Germany"}, {id:20, country:"USA"}, {id:30, country:"Australia}];
```

I would like to copy the id values of myArray into a new array based on the id property so I end up with:

```
var myNewArray = [10,20,30];
```

How do I make this copy? On other situations I may wish to copy values of the country property only so I end up with an array:

```
var myNewArray = ["Germany", "USA", "Australia"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**jQuery.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```
var arr = $.map(myArray, function (elem, index) {
    return elem.id;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/330n2ny2/)

Answer (score 0):

What about using for loop over object-

```
var arr=[];
for(var i in myArray){
arr[arr.length]=myArray[i].id;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/df6bgk8L/